# Alternative to "Hear" With Written Communication

Tags: word-choice, writing-style, writing

In person a person may say something like the following:

> I would really like to hear what you have to say about X.

On a forum (or other forms of written communication), I often see similar ideas being expressed using the word "hear." Of course, with such communication, the vast majority of the people involved will actually read what the other person has to say. As such, I am looking for an alternative to "hear" that can be used as a drop-in replacement in as many cases as possible.

Also, I know I am probably being a bit pedantic by not just using "hear," but, I would still like to know something that can more accurately convey such ideas.

Comment: "I would really like to see what you have written about X."

Comment: Discern - to detect with the senses,  to recognize or identify

Comment: @ab2 I need it to work in the future tense as well, for instance as a way to ask the other person to write a post about something.

Comment: @vickyace that strongly implies (at least to me) that it is something that carefully needs to be observed or thought about. "It took some time to descern the exact way that this code works."

Comment: "I'd be interesting in seeing anything you write about X."

Comment: @ab2 that sounds like a reasonable answer.

Comment: @john01dav You are right. But look at this - I discern a malodour or I discern an orotund voice in this babble. These certainly require attention but not by that much

Comment: @vickyace it implies that whatever text is being referred to is somehow especially difficult to understand, which often isn't the case.

Comment: @john01dav also, if we were to use "espy" as "I espied a boat in the storm, " it would to be nearly the same as "I saw a boat in the storm." I guess it's about the inflection and context.

Comment: "I would really like you to share your opinions/views about X".

Comment: @john01dav I yield. :) You're right, there might be such implications.

Comment: *read* what you have to say, not *hear* what you have to say...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "see" fits in semantically with your example:

> I would really like to **see** what you have to say about X.

This has a nice two-fold meaning, as [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see) includes a meaning of "to understand" under the entry for "see":

> [transitive verb]: to understand, know, or realize

and you would also literally use your eyes to see (read) the response.

Answer (score 4):

Some alternatives are ***learn***, ***find out***, or ***know***, for instance:

> I would really like to ***find out*** what you think about X.

I like these because they work in any medium (speech, text, etc.).

If it's a context where a direct question is acceptable, you could also just say:

> What do you think about X?

(P.S. I'm very new around here, so please be patient if I'm not answering or formatting as well as I might.  This is also why this is an answer and not a comment.)

Comment: I didn't mean to post a duplicate answer. The browser was reloading. You deserve a vote up.

Answer (score 1):

I would really like to [know](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Know) what you have to say about X.

Do I even dare define that. 
You know when you see it. 
You know when you hear it. 
You know when you touch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

> I would really like to **learn** what you have to say about X.

It is a little more formal and has the connotation of getting actually new information on a subject matter and not just an opinion.